# multiplying two sides of the equation $\ Ax = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix over some field. 
Does multiplying two sides of the equation:
 $\ Ax = 0$
with matrix $B$ ($n\times m$, over the same field), change in any way the the equation solutions space?

Comment: You right, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the $B$ in question.  For instance, if $B$ is the $n\times m$ zero matrix, any $x$ is a solution!  On the other hand, if $m=n$ and $B$ is invertible, then it has no impact on the solution space.

The solutions of $BAx=0$ are precisely those $x$ such that $Ax$ is in the nullspace of the matrix $B$.  So, if $B$ has a trivial nullspace, $BAx=0$ if and only if $Ax=0$, and the solution space is unchanged.

On the other hand, if $B$ has a non-trivial nullspace, we may gain extra solutions.  Note that we won't ever LOSE solutions, though -- if $Ax=0$, then $BAx=0$ as well.

Comment: Thank you! got my answer.